# Listbox doesn't update after adding from list

Tags: c#, list, arduino, listbox

### Edit

It now works thanks to @omaxel's

```
BindingList<string> UIDList = new BindingList<string>();
```

and

```
lbUID.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
  UIDList.Add(UID);
});
```

and @Ming Zhou's

```
//reset the DataSource
lbUID.DataSource = null;
lbUID.DataSource = UIDList;
```

---

### Original Post

The listbox in my form doesn't update after I add an item from a list to it. It does add a value to the list and the integer (beschikbarePlekken) is working as intended. Could you help me? Here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Variabelen
    SerialPort port;
    int beschikbarePlekken = 255; // Beschikbare parkeerplekken
    string UID = " ";
    List<string> UIDList = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        port = new SerialPort("COM12", 9600);
        port.DataReceived += incoming;
        port.Open();
        lbUID.DataSource = UIDList;
    }

    private void incoming(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        UID = port.ReadLine().Trim();

        if (UID.Length == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        UpdateList(UID);
    }

    delegate void SetLabel();

    public void UpdateList(string UID)
    {
        if (!UIDList.Contains(UID) && UIDList.Count < beschikbarePlekken)
        {
            UIDList.Add(UID);
            Console.WriteLine(UID);
            lblPlek.Invoke(new SetLabel(SetLabelMethod));
        }
    }

    void SetLabelMethod()
    {
        lblPlek.Text = "Beschikbare plekken: " + (beschikbarePlekken - UIDList.Count);
    }

}
```

Comment: try to set `ListBox`'s data source again. After `UIDList.Add(UID);` add `lbUID.DataSource = UIDList;`

Comment: @Nino Still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`BindingList<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `List<string>`. So, whenever you add an item to `UIDList`, the listbox will be updated.

From Microsoft Docs:

> `BindingList<string>`: Provides a generic collection that supports data binding.

Change your `UIDList` variable declaration/initialization to:

```
BindingList<string> UIDList = new BindingList<string>();
```

Also, remember to call the `Add` method of the ListBox control on the main thread. In your `UpdateList` method you could use

```
if (!UIDList.Contains(UID) && UIDList.Count < beschikbarePlekken)
{
    lbUID.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        UIDList.Add(UID);
    });

    lblPlek.Invoke(new SetLabel(SetLabelMethod));
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you ;)